# Multiple binds for a single key based on file extension in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Good Evening,

I'm trying to bind multiple actions for the same key based on the file extension of the current buffer in VSCode.

If i do it with one binding, it works perfect, but if i add a second one, with the same key, it overwrites the first one.

This is an example:

```
{"before": ["key"],"commands": [{command_1},{command_2},{etc}],"when":"resourceExtname == .ext1"}
```

If i do this, it works as expected, but if i then add another binding for the same key with another extension:

```
{"before": ["key"],"commands": [{command_3},{command_4},{etc}],"when":"resourceExtname == .ext2"}
```

It uses everytime the commands for `.ext2` files, the first keybind gets overwritten.

I'm not sure if this can be achieved somehow, or by limitation of VSCode you can't bind more than one action to the same key.

Any help would be welcome, thanks in advance!

EDIT: Forgot to add that those are bindings for the VIM plugin in VSCode.

EDIT 2: It seems to be a limitation of the Vim plugin, but one of the devs provided a workaround that indeed works, so, i'm closing it. https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/4765

Comment: where have you seen documentation for this key bind definition

Comment: you can bind as many commands to the same key if you can find a unique `when` clause

Comment: what's `"before"`? did you mean `"key"`?

Comment: VSCode, as stated. I have all my keybinds with the same syntax and they work. It's just binding two different to the same key that fails.

Comment: Are these vim bindings?  If so, that may be important.  VSCode keybindings use a different format.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `editorLangId` in the `when` expression

```json
{
  "before": ["key"],
  "commands": [{command_1},{command_2},{etc}],
  "when":"editorLangId == typescript"
}
```

Comment: That's related to the issue i'm asking about or a general advice?

Comment: what you use is not the key bind that is documented in the VSC doc, what works (I have used it) is `editorLangId` in the `when` property of a standard VSC key bind, @Ghost, and you don't answer my question where have you seen this documented for VSC, the text `"before"` is not to be found on the official VSC key bind doc page and the use of `"commands"` is incorrect

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention that, i use the VIM VSCode plugin, those are bindings for it.

Comment: @Ghost which `when` context variables does it support and does it support multiple commands on same key combo, create an issue at the vim plugin repo

Comment: Ok, for what i saw, it's a limitation of the VIM plugin, but on their github, one of the devs provided a hacky workaround for that, just using VSCode keybinds and using the context there to catch them instead of the vim plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a limitation of the VIM plugin, but one of the devs provided a workaround, just tested it and it works, so i'm closing this.

This is the workaround: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/4765